# why state returned from reducer gets wrapped in an object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using connect function from "react-redux" to map state & actions as props in my component. Used combined reducers as below :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import userDetails from "./userDetails";    
export default combineReducers({
  userDetails
});
```

On putting debugger in mapStateToProps function
[image]
, state object is not coming at top level but gets wrapped under key : userDetails which is the name of one of the reducer :

```
 import { FETCH_USER_DETAILS } from "../actions/type";

const reducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USER_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...{
          ...action.payload,
          isLoading: false
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Now since state object is not available at top level , I have to add more logic inside mapStateToProps as below :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  if (state.userDetails)
    return {
      title: state.userDetails.title,
      author: state.userDetails.author,
      rating: state.userDetails.rating,
      reviews: state.userDetails.reviews,
      isLoading: state.userDetails.isLoading
    };
  else return {};
};
```

Is there any way that state returned by reducer to the store does not gets wrapped inside any object { object key same as name of reducer}
so that I can simplify mapStateToProps function as below :

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ title, author, reviews, rating, isLoading }) => ({
  title,
  author,
  reviews,
  rating,
  isLoading
});
```

Comment: In mapStateToProps, you can do just `return state.userDetails`. No need for all the extra code.

Comment: `return { userDetials }` is shorthand for `return {userDetails: userDetails}`. `return {...userDetails}` do the trick https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingobjectspreadoperator. But maybe what you really want is `const mapStateToProps = args => ({...args})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way that state returned by reducer to the store does not gets wrapped inside any object { object key same as name of reducer} so that I can simplify mapStateToProps function as below

Yes, you can remove `combineReducers()`:

```
export default userDetails;
```

However, this doesn't seem to be a good idea to me because it means you have to keep everything in a single reducer. For simple apps, that might be okay, but for more complex apps, having top-level keys in the state object to organize data is very helpful.

With that said, I think you are doing a lot of work for little benefit in `mapStateToProps()`. You can simplify it to this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    if (state.userDetails) {
        return state.userDetails;
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ..that was quick and easy fix . Yes combined reducers make sense as different set of states  can be handled separately

Answer (score 3):

That's what `combineReducer` does here

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import userDetails from "./userDetails";    
export default combineReducers({
  userDetails
});
```

The `combineReducers` function is usually used to combine many different reducers, so each one gets 'scoped' into its own key. In your case, you're making all the work of the `userDetails` reducer (imported from the file) to live into the `userDetails` key.

If you want a flat state (which for sure, you'll change your mind later), you just either:

- export `userDetails` as-is (no need for `combineReducers`), but you'll only get to use one reducer.
- use another function to merge the states, names `reduceReducers` (check the `reduce-reducers` package on npm).